# Attempting to mock `abort` using CMocka and `gcc -Wl,wrap...`

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmocka

I am building unit tests with [CMocka](https://cmocka.org/). My function `char some_func(some_enum e)` maps valid values of `e` to a `char`. It uses `assert` to check `e` is valid, which by definition calls `abort` if not.

Mocking `abort` is proving to be hard. Following [this example](https://www.bysatish.in/3/) and building a function ...

```
static volatile abort_calls = 0;

void 
__wrap_abort(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Call to __wrap_abort()\n");
    abort_calls++;
}

static void
test_some_func(void **state)
{
    some_func( (some_enum)99);
    assert_int_equal(1, abort_calls);
}
```

.. that when compiled with `-Wl,--wrap=abort` makes no complaints. However, when executed it does *not* call `__wrap_abort`.

Is what I'm attempting even possible?

Comment: The wrap stuff is dangerous to use with `abort`. See this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725138/strange-behaviour-while-wrapping-abort-system-call/39725443#39725443